# Убрать красную рамку в Toast в поле text

Tags: android, android-studio, android-toast

Коллеги, установил андроид студио 3.5.2

Набираю Toast затем по таб перехожу ввожу текст, ввожу его, у меня он выделяется красной рамкой.

Как мне оставляя курсор на месте убрать красную обводку?

[image: Пример]

Comment: Нажать `Esc` не пробовали?

Comment: благодарю , помогло

Comment: нажмите Tab ...

Comment: Таб переводит каретку дальше..а если требуется внести в ресурсы текст по alt+enter неудобно возвращаться назад, поэтому ESC лучший вариант